# What does GDAL's function addo stand for?

Tags: gdal

This is sort of a superficial question. I can't seem to find the meaning behind the naming convention of [gdaladdo](https://gdal.org/programs/gdaladdo.html). My guess is that *addo* stands for "add overview"? Does anyone else know or have a better guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, it means "add overviews". The description has been changed later when it became possible to also rebuild and remove existing overviews. For example here you can see the description of gdaladdo as it was in GDAL version 1.4

https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/branches/1.4/gdal/dist_docs/README_WIN_BIN.TXT

> ### Utility Programs
>
> The following GDAL and OGR utility programs should be available in the bin directory.  Visit the GDAL web page for more information on the utility
> programs.
>
> gdalinfo.exe: Report summary information about a GDAL supported raster file.
>
> gdal_translate.exe: Translate GDAL supported raster files into other formats.
>
> **gdaladdo: Add overviews to selected GDAL supported formats.**
>
> ogrinfo: Dump information about OGR supported vector formats.
>
> ogr2ogr: Translate OGR supported vector formats to OGR supported formats.

Description was still the same in GDAL 2.2 that was the last version in trac https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/branches/2.2/gdal/apps/gdal_utilities.dox.

The change has happened when source code was moved from trac into GitHub. The very first version of the gdaladdo manual page in GitHub is
https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/commit/b5dedc24d4d210bdca5d16fcec8c22d5b7002445#diff-00a44a66d0e58723ba1ba71fccca0d903d941abd75e1bc4af1d494873b357012

and there the description is

> The `gdaladdo` utility can be used to build or rebuild overview images
> for most supported file formats with one of several downsampling
> algorithms.